# Nunit what is your experience involving it

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

How NUnit has helped you to come out with your solution for unit tests? How fast you were able to implement it from the scratch? Any tips can be given which will help us to implement Nunit quickly and efficiently?

Comment: To implement **what** from the scratch?

Comment: Introduce Nunit based unit tests onto fully developed project

Comment: @PradeepGB: if you ask such questions - I bet you'll not be able to introduce unit testing at all. Nothing personal, just unit tests require highly experienced developers and good code.

Comment: You might want to pick up a copy of [
Brownfield Application Development in .NET](http://www.manning.com/baley/); it isn't specific to NUnit, but covers a range of factors when considering adding tests to existing code.

Comment: If this question becomes about literature, why no one mentioned "Test Driven Development" by Kent Beck?

Comment: The title doesn't match the content of the question - NUnit as a tool has been pretty stable for years and has lots of devs using it daily. However learning and being proficient at unit-testing is much more difficult and has a longer learning curve.. i'd focus on the latter than on a specific tool.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up an NUnit Test project is the work of a few moments:  Add new Class Library project, add NUnit Framework reference, and you're done.

How easily your code is unit testable depends on how easy it is to isolate from any other code.

A method which has no dependencies, is going to be the easiest to test - but least likely to be particularly useful. Most often, you're calling some other class to do something.

A method which has all it's dependencies specific in the class constructor will be straightforward to test - so long as you can Isolate the dependencies and pass those in.

A method which directly calls other classes is going to be more difficult to test, and may not be possible to do a strict unit test depending on how deeply intertwined it is.

Look up and understand the difference between the types of Testing.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read the following book:
http://www.manning.com/osherove/ 
Will definitely speed up your learning curve. If you have sufficient experience you can get started after the first three chapters (one weekend). Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Pragmatic-Unit-Testing-NUnit-2nd/dp/0977616673/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0977616673)